# Aalen model with interaction gives all NAs for coefficients in R

Tags: r, regression, survival, interaction, model

I'm a long time lurker and first time question asker so my apologies in advance for any errors or missing information in my question.

I'm running a semi-parametric aalen regression model in R using the package timereg. My goal is to determine the effect of a two-way interaction between individual and neighbourhood income on survival. Both individual and neighbourhood education have 5 levels giving me an interaction with 25 levels. I have a reasonable sample size of 26,000 and the smallest number of events in the 5*5 interaction is 200.

The problem I have is that when I run the regression with only the interaction and no main effects it runs fine, but when I add the main effects it gives me 0s and NaNs for all coefficients. I read that it could be a problem with multicolinearity but when I check the correlation between individual and neighbourhood education it is only 0.20. Also, the models run fine in coxph as cox models.

Any help on why I might be getting NaNs would be greatly appreciated!

Unfortunately my code and data are in a protected environment but below is an example:

Interaction only (results as expected):

```
df$interact <- interaction(df$ind, df$neighb)
mod1<-aalen(Surv(time_new,status==1)~const(interact), df)
```

Interaction + main effects (results like the example below):

```
mod2<-aalen(Surv(time_new,status==1)~const(ind):const(neighb), df)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV.  My first thought is to check the input data is properly conditioned, and that you set up the problem properly.  Some solvers will give all na if there is only one na in inputs.  If you have 1/0 in the way the problem is set up, some solvers will also choke.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have no NAs in the input data and all variables are formatted as factors (categorical variables).

Comment: What you wrote with the `:` should have given _only_  the interaction in R and not the "main effects." This might be a coding problem with the way that the `timereg` package handles its `const()` wrapper. Coding questions are off-topic on this site. Try instead `~const(ind) + const(neighb) + const(interact)` to get both the "main effects" and the interaction.  If there's still a problem there might be an on-topic statistical issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure what the problem is without the data, but it might be simple to fix. Here's a synthetic dataset:

```
library(timereg)
library(wakefield)
library(tidyverse)

test_data <- tibble(ind = wakefield::r_sample(500, c(1,2,3,4,5)),
                neighb = wakefield::r_sample(500, c(1,2,3,4,5)),
                status = wakefield::death(500))

test_data <- test_data |> 
  mutate(time_new = rnorm(500, 200, 30)) |> 
  filter(time_new > 0) |> 
  mutate(time_new = time_new + ind * 5 + neighb * 8 + ind * neighb) |> 
  mutate(across(neighb:ind, as.factor))
```

The model that you say works in your data works here as well:

```
test_data$interact <- interaction(test_data$ind, test_data$neighb)
aalen(Surv(time_new, status==1)~const(interact), test_data) 

Parametric terms :     
              Coef.  SE Robust SE     z    P-val lower2.5% upper 97.5%
const(interact)2.1 -0.001930 0.001140  0.000800 -2.41 1.60e-02  -0.00416   3.04e-04
```

This model does not work:

```
aalen(Surv(time_new,status==1)~const(ind):const(neighb), test_data) 

Parametric terms :     
              Coef.  SE Robust SE     z    P-val lower2.5% upper 97.5%
const(ind)1:const(neighb)1     0  0         0 NaN   NaN         0          0
```

But you can use 'x*y' to mean 'x, y, and their interaction' in formulas in R, and it appears to work here - maybe some problem with how the package is interpreting formulas? Who knows...

```
mod3 <- aalen(Surv(time_new, status==1)~const(neighb)*const(ind), test_data)
```

```
Additive Aalen Model 

Test for nonparametric terms 

Test for non-significant effects 
            Supremum-test of significance p-value H_0: B(t)=0
(Intercept)                          12.1                   0

Test for time invariant effects 
                  Kolmogorov-Smirnov test p-value H_0:constant effect
(Intercept)                          2.26                           0
                    Cramer von Mises test p-value H_0:constant effect
(Intercept)                          1020                           0

Parametric terms :     
                               Coef.       SE Robust SE      z    P-val lower2.5% upper97.5%
const(neighb)2             -0.000943 0.001180  0.000796 -1.180 2.36e-01 -0.003260   1.37e-03
const(neighb)3             -0.002280 0.001050  0.000715 -3.180 1.45e-03 -0.004340  -2.22e-04
const(neighb)4             -0.002270 0.001070  0.000821 -2.770 5.66e-03 -0.004370  -1.73e-04
const(neighb)5             -0.003740 0.000976  0.000644 -5.820 6.04e-09 -0.005650  -1.83e-03
const(ind)2                -0.001930 0.001140  0.000800 -2.410 1.60e-02 -0.004160   3.04e-04
const(ind)3                -0.002110 0.000983  0.000625 -3.370 7.55e-04 -0.004040  -1.83e-04
const(ind)4                -0.002070 0.001170  0.001000 -2.060 3.92e-02 -0.004360   2.23e-04
const(ind)5                -0.002100 0.001080  0.000811 -2.580 9.77e-03 -0.004220   1.68e-05
const(neighb)2:const(ind)2  0.002130 0.001620  0.001150  1.860 6.34e-02 -0.001050   5.31e-03
const(neighb)3:const(ind)2  0.001450 0.001430  0.001110  1.300 1.92e-01 -0.001350   4.25e-03
const(neighb)4:const(ind)2  0.000954 0.001490  0.001190  0.803 4.22e-01 -0.001970   3.87e-03
const(neighb)5:const(ind)2  0.002400 0.001380  0.001020  2.350 1.86e-02 -0.000305   5.10e-03
const(neighb)2:const(ind)3  0.001110 0.001440  0.001040  1.070 2.84e-01 -0.001710   3.93e-03
const(neighb)3:const(ind)3  0.003200 0.001420  0.000952  3.360 7.76e-04  0.000417   5.98e-03
const(neighb)4:const(ind)3  0.001340 0.001410  0.001070  1.250 2.11e-01 -0.001420   4.10e-03
const(neighb)5:const(ind)3  0.001900 0.001270  0.001030  1.840 6.60e-02 -0.000589   4.39e-03
const(neighb)2:const(ind)4  0.000779 0.001600  0.001390  0.562 5.74e-01 -0.002360   3.91e-03
const(neighb)3:const(ind)4  0.001120 0.001460  0.001300  0.860 3.90e-01 -0.001740   3.98e-03
const(neighb)4:const(ind)4  0.000580 0.001470  0.001370  0.423 6.73e-01 -0.002300   3.46e-03
const(neighb)5:const(ind)4  0.002080 0.001380  0.001180  1.770 7.74e-02 -0.000625   4.78e-03
const(neighb)2:const(ind)5  0.000710 0.001580  0.001110  0.637 5.24e-01 -0.002390   3.81e-03
const(neighb)3:const(ind)5  0.000412 0.001330  0.001130  0.365 7.15e-01 -0.002190   3.02e-03
const(neighb)4:const(ind)5 -0.000248 0.001380  0.001200 -0.206 8.37e-01 -0.002950   2.46e-03
const(neighb)5:const(ind)5 -0.000194 0.001280  0.001030 -0.188 8.51e-01 -0.002700   2.31e-03
   
  Call: 
aalen(formula = Surv(time_new, status == 1) ~ const(neighb) * 
    const(ind), data = test_data)
```

Comment: Hey @Randy! Using "*" instead of ":" definitely works and my models run fine now. Thanks for your help.